# "Install New Software" on Eclipse 3.4.2

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.4

For reasons beyond my control, one of the projects I inherited is stuck with Eclipse **3.4.2** (Ganymede) as its maintenance environment.

I now need to install the JD-Eclipse plug-in but [its instructions](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) refer to a non-existent menu item on Eclipse 3.4.2, `Install New Software...`:

[image]

The installation steps themselves are quite simple -- **if** the `Install New Software...` menu item were there, that is:

```
Add a new repository to add JD-Eclipse plug-in:    

 1. Click on the Add... button to open the New Repository dialog window.    
 2. Type JD-Eclipse Update Site in the site Name text box. 
 3. In the URL text box, type the URL for the JD-Eclipse update site: http://jd.benow.ca/jd-eclipse/update and click OK.
```

But for lack of that menu item, the aforementioned steps aren't readily accessible.

Any idea how to workaround this missing menu item?

What is the proper way of installing a new plugin in Eclipse 3.4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Help" -> "Software Updates...", go to the "Available Software" tab, choose to "Add Site...", then enter the update site. From there it should behave similarly to how to behaves in newer versions.

Alternatively you can download the plugin files and then [install it manually, without using an update site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580832/how-to-install-a-custom-plug-in-in-eclipse-ganymede).

Keep in mind that the plugin may not be compatible with your Eclipse version, though.

Comment: Your instructions through the `Software Updates...` work like a charm. I didn't realize it would be so simple. Thank you!